# How to apply formula to a whole column?

Tags: excel, formula

I need to subtract the minimum of that column from all rows of the column in Excel. I have one million rows and I cannot drag the right corner of the cell box all the way down to apply the formula to all those cells. I unfortunately haven't found anything that works. I want to subtract the minimum of a column from each cell of that column divide by 1000 and store in another column:

```
=(B1-MIN(B:B))/1000
```

How do I apply this to all rows of the column where I want this to work?

How do we apply formulas in general to all rows of a column in general?

Comment: do all the rows contain data in column B? If so select the top cell with where the formula you entered and double-click on the lower-right corner of the cell and it will down the entire column. See **Data** in the ribbon, then **Sort** for sorting.

Comment: hi, there are some empty cells at the end of the table,but not in between

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to apply a formula to a new column in a large data set:

Option 1 - turn the data into a table: Assuming the data has headers, select the data and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> or use Insert > table and tick the box "My table has headers". Now enter a name for the new calculated column and below the header enter the formula. It will automatically be applied to all rows in the table.

Option 2 - Enter the formula in the first row of next empty column of the data range. Then double click the fill handle (the lower right-hand corner of the selected cell) to fill the formula all the way down to the last row of the data range

Option 3 - Select the cells where the new formula should go. Easiest might be to start at the bottom end of the data and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>up arrow</kbd> to select up to the top. Adjust the selection to suit and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make the top cell the current cell. Enter the formula and confirm it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will be applied to all selected cells.

Comment: where is the fill handle? I did as you said but it dint work :( (I used option 2)

Comment: the fill handle is the lower right corner of the active cell. You can drag it down or you can double click it to fill as far down as the neighboring columns have data. It won't work if the neighboring columns are empty.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the column, say it's A. In a couple of spare cells enter:

```
=MIN(A:A)
```

and

```
1000
```

Copy the formula cell, Paste Special..., Values over the top. Copy that cell, select the copy of ColumnA, Paste Special..., Operation Subtract. Copy the cell containing `1000`, select the copied column, Paste Special..., Operation Divide. Filter ColumnA to select blanks and delete the contents on the copied column for the selected rows.